# How to handle error when socket.io emits a message?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a route to send a message. The message is first saved in the database, and then broadcasted to every chat subscribers in the room. The message is successfully saved, but the server (node/express/typescript) crashes when hitting the socket.io instance. The error is:

> err send message Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting
> at BroadcastOperator.emit (/Users/myname/Desktop/Code/myapp/server/node_modules/socket.io/dist/broadcast-operator.js:107:19)

The route is:

```js
import { Response, Request } from "express";
import { ConversationControler } from "../../controllers/conversation";
import { SocketControler } from "../../controllers/socket";

interface SendMessage extends Request {
  body: {
    conversationName: string;
    userId: string;
    message: string;
  };
}

const sendMessage = async (req: SendMessage, res: Response): Promise<any> => {
  try {
    const { conversationName, userId,  message } = req.body;
    await ConversationControler.sendMessage(
      conversationName,
      userId,
      message
    );
    const io = req.app.locals.io;
    SocketControler.dispatchMessage(io, conversationName, message);
    return res.status(201)
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.send-message");
  }
};

export default sendMessage;
```

The sendMessage function is:

```js
static dispatchMessage(
    io: Server,
    conversationName: string,
    message: string
  ) {
    return io
      .in(`chat@${conversationName}`)
      .emit("newMessage", message, (err: Error) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error("error.send-message");
        }
      });
  }
```

If I remove the callback, the request in postman run forever. I let it, the server crashes. In any case, the message is saved in the database.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When broadcasting callbacks are not supported. It'll only work when you are emitting to a single user.

Like this:

```
// client-side
socket.emit("update item", "1", { name: "updated" }, (response) => {
  console.log(response.status); // ok
});
```